# Parallel bucket sort: send elements to appropriate buckets

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, bucket-sort

I'm designing a parallel bucket sort algorithm. Each processor is assigned a bucket, which has an interval of values it will accept. The master process must go through the original unsorted array and give each element to the appropriate process/bucket (i.e. the interval in which that value is).

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. Is there an MPI function that can fulfill this purpose? If not, does that mean the elements must be distributed to buckets BEFORE the processes are assigned to buckets?

Comment: I wonder whether or not you googled or searched it on stackoverflow.

Comment: I did. I always do before posting on stackoverflow

Comment: I'm not sure how a program could efficiently perform the bucket distribution of to multiple threads as described, since simple indexing is going to be much faster than any inter-thread or inter-process interface. Most of what I've seen for parallel sorts for k processors is to split up the array into k parts, do parallel sorts on the k parts, then merge the k sorted parts.